# $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, assume that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$ exist. Is it true that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_n(x)$. I can't think of a counterexample.

Comment: No, consider $$f_n(x)=\left\lbrace \begin{array}{cc} x^n & \text{if } x\leq 1 \\ 1 & \text{if } x>1 \end{array}\right.$$ and $a=1$.
The additional assumption you need to add to get the property is the [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) of the sequence $(f_n)$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Does $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1}\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ exist in that example?

Comment: Consider $f_n(x) = n(x-a)$ : taking $x$ to $a$ first , we will get over-all limit $X = 0$ : taking $n$ to $\infty$ first , we will get over-all limit $Y = \infty$ : We can easily **tweak** this function in various ways , to get various $X$ & $Y$ values !!

Comment: @Henry You are right, it does not. In my defense, even if my example does not answer properly the question, it still shows what can be the problem to have different values for the two limits.

Comment: Is anything wrong with my answer?

Answer (score -2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Iterated_limit_of_function

$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+\frac1n}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to0}f_n(x)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=1$$

---

On the other hand, if you take the outer limit in

$$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$$

to include $x=a$ in its domain, i.e. if you require $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ to be continuous at $a$, then it is true:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to a}f_n(x)$$

since each $f_n$ is continuous at $a$.